# How to set the point on range div?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, slice

I have one range `div` in my asp.net MVC project where the leftmost point and right most point contain the max and min values respectively, like (max=400 and min=0). I want to set the point on the div with the given range.

For example: When I set 399 as the point value then my div look like the following picture.

[image: example picture]

How do I set the point on the range `div`?

Note: I don't need a HTML slider, My point is fixed and doesn't need a UI change. The value should be written under the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```js
   $('.scoreContainer').find('.score').each(function() {
      var high = $(this).attr('data-high'),
        low = $(this).attr('data-low'),
        score = $(this).attr('data-score');
      var position = ((score - low) / (high - low)) * 100

      $(this).find('.arrow').css('right', position + "%");
      $(this).find('.arrow').html('<span>' + score + '</span>');
    });
```

```css
    .scoreContainer {
  background: #ff3232;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%, #ffff30 50%, #95ef81 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%, #ffff30 50%, #95ef81 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3232 0%, #ffff30 50%, #95ef81 100%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;
}
.score{
   width: 33.33%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% - 5px);
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow span {
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 8px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="scoreContainer">
   <div class="green score" data-high="600" data-low="400" data-score="475">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="yelow score" data-high="399" data-low="200" data-score="201">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="red score" data-high="199" data-low="0" data-score="99">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: Syntax work perfectly, need some enhancement, as you see the question description there are three color bar, their range is 100-199: Low,200-299: Medium,
300-399: High, base on range how to fix the arrow on those color bar?

Comment: So you need to have an arrow for each color, three in total ?

Comment: yah, there is total, base on the total need to set the arrow on each color.

Comment: I made some changes, so there is three arrows now.
But remember SO is about getting help with your code and not please make it for me. Next time, you need to make an effort trying to do it yourself, and not just make me do it, even thought it is easier. 
And also there is going to be a overlapping off the numbers and arrows, if the two score is close, like 199 and 200. So you still need to tweak it, so it suit you best.